# httptest.NewRequest vs http.NewRequest: which one to use in tests and why?

Tags: unit-testing, go, request

Golang has these two similar libs `http` and `httptest` and they both have the `NewRequest` func.

Why do we even need the `httptest.NewRequest` if `http.NewRequest` does it all?

If I need to create a multipart/multiform request for my tests, which one do I need to use?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As indicated in the documentation, [`httptest.NewRequest`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/#NewRequest) "returns a new incoming server Request, suitable for passing to an http.Handler for testing", while [`http.NewRequest`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#NewRequest) "returns a Request suitable for use with Client.Do or Transport.RoundTrip." So, if you're passing the request directly to the handler in a unit test, use `httptest.NewRequest`, and if you're executing a full round-trip using `http.Client`, use `http.NewRequest`.